# Как узнать что картинка с сервера полностью загружена

Tags: java, android

Есть способ загрузки cover-ов в новостной ленте: перебор массива с урлами и загрузка:

```
Bufferinputstreem buf = New Bufferinputstreem(con.getInStreem,512)
```

и создание

```
bitmap = Bitmapfactory.DecodeStreem(buf)
```

Если происходит обрыв соединения, то картинка загружается не полностью, как это отловить. У меня есть кэш, который создаётся после загрузки. Какая ошибка появляется в результате обрыва соединения при скачивании? SSLExeption? Может можно по размеру файла? Как мне понять, что картинка загрузилась не полностью?

Comment: можно по размеру файла как вы и предположили, это мне кажется самый нормальный вариант

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить эту картинку в ImageView  если возникнет exception, то видимо что-то ни так. Может так?